# How to install Homebank 5.1rc

Tags: software-installation

Homebank is a free software & was easily installable in past. Recently France has banned it's various sites due to cyber attacks. Please let me know how to download/install Homebank 5.1rc released in August 2016

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Ubuntu 16.04 - the default repositories offer currently homebank 5.0.3-2.

The [launchpad-page](https://launchpad.net/homebank/5.1.x) lists no released 5.1 versions so far.

5.1rc is according to the [project page](http://homebank.free.fr/downloads.php#prerelease) a pre-release - which results in the following warnings:

- use the prerelease version for testing only
- backup your usual homebank file before doing anything
- never save your usual homebank file with prerelease (change the name at least)

Ignoring those - the only option on Linux so far is [downloading the source](http://homebank.free.fr/public/homebank-5.1-rc.tar.gz) and then compiling the rc yourself on your machine.
The source archiv contains instructions how to compile/install the software - consider reading the detailed instructions in the file `INSTALL`.

Seems like it might be better to wait for a final 5.1 release.